# MongoLab and Heroku without mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I am currently working with a team in a NodeJS project that uses express and a local MongoDB database.

We did not implement mongoose into the project, and now we are at a stage where we wish to upload the project using heroku, so that we can have a central point as we further develop different parts of the project (apps and web pages that consume the data from the database.)

We managed to upload the project to heroku, and some of the pages are working, but we can't access the database, it returns "500 - internal server error" everytime we try to access data from the MongoDB.

After some research we could only find that it's best to use MongoLAB to store the data in a cloud based datacenter, but we can't seem to find ways to connect our project with MongoLab without the use of mongoose, which we didn't install to the project.

My question is: is there a way to connect our NodeJS project to MongoLab using only the original MongoDB npm module, without having to install and use mongoose? We are at a stage that refactoring our DB-access classes, and implement mongoose, would cause our project's deadline to be delayed.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use mongoDB with mLab(previously mongoLab), without using mongoose.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://ID:PASSWORD!@SUBDOMAIN.mlab.com:PORT/DATABASE_NAME', function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
  db.close();
});
```